# Showing course image on custom page in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I have created a custom page on which all available courses are displayed. I have also uploaded the image for the course and now want to show the name of the course along with the image. I am able to get the names of courses from the database but how to get the image.

Comment: Are you using Totara or Moodle?

Comment: Moodle(Version- 3.0)

Comment: How did you upload the image for the course? Was it an image in the summary? https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Course_settings#Course_summary_files

Comment: yes, uploaded it in course summary files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
// Create a course_in_list object to use the get_course_overviewfiles() method.
require_once($CFG->libdir . '/coursecatlib.php');
$course = new course_in_list($courseid);

$outputimage = '';
foreach ($course->get_course_overviewfiles() as $file) {
    if ($file->is_valid_image()) {
        $imagepath = '/' . $file->get_contextid() .
                '/' . $file->get_component() .
                '/' . $file->get_filearea() .
                $file->get_filepath() .
                $file->get_filename();
        $imageurl = file_encode_url($CFG->wwwroot . '/pluginfile.php', $imagepath,
                false);
        $outputimage = html_writer::tag('div',
                html_writer::empty_tag('img', array('src' => $imageurl)),
                array('class' => 'courseimage'));
        // Use the first image found.
        break;
    }
}
echo $outputimage;
```

Comment: Just a small improvement: As of Moodle 3.6 `course_in_list` is deprecated. Use `core_course_list_element` instead, which does not require `coursecatlib`. Everything else works fine

Answer (score 1):

You may get course image directly from 'overviewfiles' files area.

```php
    function get_course_image()
    {
       global $COURSE;
       $url = '';
       require_once( $CFG->libdir . '/filelib.php' );

       $context = context_course::instance( $COURSE->id );
       $fs = get_file_storage();
       $files = $fs->get_area_files( $context->id, 'course', 'overviewfiles', 0 );

       foreach ( $files as $f )
       {
         if ( $f->is_valid_image() )
         {
            $url = moodle_url::make_pluginfile_url( $f->get_contextid(), $f->get_component(), $f->get_filearea(), null, $f->get_filepath(), $f->get_filename(), false );
         }
       }

       return $url;
    }
```